# Pass an array of places from tableview to mapview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, mkmapview

Here is my tableview controller. I declared my array of mapSearch in the class to pass.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    let selectedMap = mapSearch[indexPath.row]

    let mapviewDestination = MapViewController()
    mapviewDestination.mapString = selectedMap

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)


}
```

Here is my mapViewController code.

```
var mapString : String?
```

The actual search.

```
var request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = mapString
    request.region = self.placeMap.region
    var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch.init(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler {
        (response:MKLocalSearchResponse!, error:NSError!) in
        if !(error != nil) {
            var placemarks:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            for item in response.mapItems {
                placemarks.addObject((item as MKMapItem).placemark)
            }
            self.placeMap.removeAnnotations(self.placeMap.annotations)
            self.placeMap.showAnnotations(placemarks, animated: true)
        } else {

        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I run the simulator it doesn't search based on the mapString.

Any ideas are welcome!

**EDIT:**

I have been trying this and no luck:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let selectedMap = mapSearch[indexPath.row]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: self)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        var mapController = segue.destinationViewController as MapViewController
        mapController.mapString = mapSearch
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `mapviewDestination` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't released and destroyed? You're assigning it a `mapString` but you're not doing anything with it.

The search is performed on a nil (or empty) string because you never actually set a `mapString`.

If you need to pass data between two view controllers using segues, you should be using `UIViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:sender:` (you just re-implement it in your presenting view controller). It gives you a pointer to the presented view controller that you can configure just before it gets on screen.

Comment: Doesn't prepareForSegue send all the values in the array? I want to just send the selected tableview's value to the mapView.

Comment: `prepareForSegue` is a method that Apple provides you to perform custom configuration of a newly push/presented view controller using a segue. Typically, you would perform the segue using its identifier (just like you did), implement `prepareForSegue` by getting a reference to the new view controller, and then set its custom properties. That way, it will be pushed/presented with an already set model.

Comment: Your issue is that you cannot instantiate `MapViewController` like you do, since the reference to the controller is lost at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You're actually passing it a mapString, but the whole configured view controller is destroyed afterwards. You should let the segue instantiate the view controller, and handle the configuration in `prepareForSegue`. Hope this helps.